# Multivariate Discrete Distribution -Hidden multinomial

Tags: probability-distributions, random-variables

In this experiment :

1- We toss n fair coins. $X_1$ is the number of heads obtained.

2-Toss again the remaining $R_1=n-X_1$ coins. $X_2$ is the number of heads obtained this time.

3-Toss again the remaining $R_2=n-X_2-X_1$ coins. $X_3$ is the number of heads obtained this time.

I have to find the joint probability mass function of $X_1,X_2,R_2$ and the marginal probability mass functions of $X_2$ and $R_2$.

Now, the joint pmf should be $$P(x_1,x_2,r_2)= \frac{n!}{x_1!x_2!r_2!}\left(\frac{1}{2}\right)^{2n-x_1},$$
because $$P(x_1)={{n}\choose{x_1}}{\left(\frac{1}{2}\right)^{n}},$$
namely a binomial with $p=1-p=1/2$, and 
$$P(X_2=x_2|X_1=x_1)={{n-x_1}\choose{x_2}}{\left(\frac{1}{2}\right)^{n-x_1}},$$
simply another binomial with $n-x_1$ trials and still $p=1-p=1/2$.

Then $P(x_1,x_2,r_2)=P(x_1,x_2)$, because $R_2=n-X_1-X_2$ is fixed by the values of $X_1$ and $X_2$.

If I am correct, I then have to calculate the marginals of  $X_2$ and $R_2$. The only thing which comes to my mind is to sum over the other variables, the usual definition of marginals.
However, I see no way of simplifying the resulting sums, for example
$$P(X_2=x_2)=\sum_{x_1}^{n}\sum_{r_2}^{n-x_1-x_2}  \frac{n!}{x_1!x_2!r_2!}\left(\frac{1}{2}\right)^{2n-x_1}$$
What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

Found the answer.

The variables $X_1,X_2,R_2$ follow a multinomial with probabilities of success given, respectively, by $p_1=1/2$,$p_2=1/4$,$p_{R_2}=1/4$.

Indeed, the joint pmf can be written as $$P(x_1,x_2,r_2)= \frac{n!}{x_1!x_2!r_2!}\left(\frac{1}{2}\right)^{x_1}\left(\frac{1}{4}\right)^{x_2}
\left(\frac{1}{4}\right)^{r_2},$$
with $r_2= n-x_1-x_2$ which is the same as

$$\frac{n!}{x_1!x_2!r_2!}\left(\frac{1}{2}\right)^{2n-x_1}.$$

Therefore it suffices to refer to the propertie of multinomial distributions.
The marginals (which are binomial distributions) can be found either analytically, through irksome summations, or by a probabilistic proof showing that each of $X_1,X_2,R_2$ follows a binomial.